# Excel VBA - Unable to remove extra spaces between words using Trim and similar functions

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove unnecessary white space in a string using VBA but the trim funciton doesn't seem to work for me. I want to remove the extra space between 'End' and 'Time' in this hypothetical example.

```
Public Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Dim s As String: s = "START TIME: N/A END     TIME: N/A "

    s = Trim(s)

    Debug.Print s

    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How about looping a few times replacing `"  "` with `" "` (double space with single space) and then trimming?

Comment: I am looking for a cleaner solution but will resort to that if I can't find anything else. I am dealing with large paragraphs of text

Comment: Have you tried `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim` function? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400293/vba-unable-to-remove-the-spaces

Comment: @AlexisOlson I apologize. This works for the example I gave but not for larger paragraphs with line breaks. However Il accept hsts answer since it answers the example I gave.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include that information since otherwise this question is just a duplicate of the one I linked.

Comment: Probably [clean](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-clean-function) would work if that blank space is caused due to importing from somewhere else

Comment: @Sgdva Yes the data is imported from Word

Comment: If clean can't handle it, you will have no other option than loop through the elements or try regex -personally I didn't think about it when I faced this problem too-. I think the answers here are accurate already on the approaches possible for this.

Comment: @Sgdva I'm dealing with NBSP (Non breaking spaces) when importing sentences (strings) from Word and none of these solutions work. I fixed it by s = Replace(s, Chr(160), "") and it worked

Comment: VBA Clean function does not clean NBSP apparently

Comment: @BDillan - Add a NBSP inside the brackets in the regex below:  `.Pattern = "[  ]+"`.  You can enter it in the VBE with ALT + 0,1,6,0 (at least in my locale). NOTE: Don't try to copy from the comment - copy-paste isn't kind to the NBSP around here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest (and probably the best performing) way of doing this is with a regular expression:

```
'Requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular expressions
Private Function RemoveExtraSpace(inVal As String) As String
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\s+"
        .Global = True
        RemoveExtraSpace = .Replace(inVal, " ")
    End With
End Function

Sub Example()
    Dim s As String
    s = "START TIME: N/A END     TIME: N/A "

    Debug.Print RemoveExtraSpace(s)
End Sub
```

Late bound version:

```
Private Function RemoveExtraSpace(inVal As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\s+"
        .Global = True
        RemoveExtraSpace = .Replace(inVal, " ")
    End With
End Function
```

**EDIT:** If per comments you need multiline, just added the additional parameter:

```
With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\s+"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    RemoveExtraSpace = .Replace(inVal, " ")
End With
```

If you want the line breaks to remain, change the pattern to `.Pattern = "[ ]+"` (brackets for readability).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe app.Worksheetfunction.Trim?

```
Public Sub RemoveSpaces()

    Dim s As String: s = "START TIME: N/A END     TIME: N/A "

    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(s)

    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

Oh, I see @Alexis Olson was first with this.

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have more up votes. It may not be the most performant but it is by far the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'd use the `split` function and then join the pieces back together.

```
Dim s As String: s = "START TIME: N/A END     TIME: N/A "
sParts = Split(s, " ")
s_wo_xtra_space = ""
for i = lbound(sParts) to ubound(sParts)
    if sParts(i) <> "" then
        s_wo_xtra_space = s_wo_xtra_space & sParts(i) & " "
    end if
next i
s_wo_xtra_space = trim(s_wo_xtra_space)
```

This assumes you still want one space between words.

Comment: By splitting on the space you will end up with 11 items.  If you do not put logic in the loop to skip the empty items the end result will look just like the input

Answer (score 1):

You can use split() to split on the spaces then loop through and skip all the empty items in the resultant array:

```
Public Sub RemoveSpaces()

Dim s As String: s = "START TIME: N/A END     TIME: N/A "
Dim str() As String
Dim str1

str = Split(s)
s = ""
For Each str1 In str
    If str1 <> "" Then
        s = s & str1 & " "
    End If
Next str1

s = Trim(s)


Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
do until instr(s, "  ") = 0
s = replace(s, "  ", " ")
loop
```

Or if you want to do a UDF you can do something like this, then to remove double spaces you can just do s = RmvDblSpc(s)

```
Function RmvDblSpc(What As String) As String

Do Until InStr(What, "  ") = 0

    What = Replace(What, "  ", " ")

Loop

RmvDblSpc = What

End Function
```