# Rename text file based on first line of text

Tags: vba, text

I have a list of text files (all different names.txt, but small files).

I want to rename them based on the first line of text in the file.

Some files have a few enters before the text. So the code returns with a (blank).txt.

```
Sub RenameTextFile()

    Const SpecialCharacters As String = "\,/,:,*,?,<,>,|,""," ' Modify this as neccesary
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine
    Dim char As Variant

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fol = fso.GetFolder("C:\Research syntheses - Meta analysis\Txt files ECS\out\")

    For Each fil In fol.Files

        FileName = fil

        Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

        Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True

            Do
                Dim tmpLine As String
                TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
                tmpLine = RemoveWhiteSpace(TextLine)
                If Len(tmpLine) = 0 Then
                    TextLine = tmpLine
                End If
            Loop Until Len(TextLine) > 0
            MyFile.Close

            For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
                TextLine = Replace(TextLine, char, "")
            Next

            fil.Name = TextLine & ".txt"
            Exit Do

        Loop

        MyFile.Close
    Next fil
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another loop to your code like that

```
Sub RenameTextFile()


    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fol = fso.GetFolder("d:\tmp\")

    For Each fil In fol.Files

        FileName = fil

        Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

        Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True

            Do
                Dim tmpLine As String
                TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
                tmpLine = removeWhiteSpace(TextLine)
                If Len(tmpLine) = 0 Then
                    TextLine = tmpLine
                End If
            Loop Until Len(TextLine) > 0
            MyFile.Close

            If isValidFilename(Trim(TextLine)) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                fil.Name = Trim(TextLine) & ".txt"
                On Error Goto 0
            Else
                MsgBox "Renaming: " & fil.Name & " -to- " & Trim(TextLine) & " failed", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Invalid Filename"
            End If

            Exit Do

        Loop

        MyFile.Close
    Next fil
End Sub
```

On the long run you need to think about kind of error handling as a file with the same name might already exist. And my extra loop will also fail in case one of the files only contains empty lines.

**Update** By the OP's comment I strongly guess that some of the files contain white spaces at the beginning and the OP is not aware of that. One can use the following function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306511/6600940)) to remove these

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Public Function RemoveWhiteSpace(ByVal target As String) As String
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\s"
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        RemoveWhiteSpace = .Replace(target, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

This will remove also white spaces from textline even if you want to keep them as the empty spaces in the line of your picture.

**Update 2**: In order to avoid invalid filename add the following function

```
Function isValidFilename(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
'PURPOSE: Determine If A Given Excel File Name Is Valid
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

  With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "[\\/:\*\?""<>\|\[\]]"
    ValidFileName = Not .Test(FileName)
  End With

End Function
```

I modified the main procedure.

Comment: Your solution does not work. Below a snap of how my files (for example) can start:      https://i.stack.imgur.com/hde9s.png

Comment: To be honest, saying it does not work is not really helpful. I told you you need to implement some kind of [error handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/). Anyway, according to your image I do not see any reason that my extra loop should fail unless you have some certain white spaces at the beginning of the file which no one can see on a picture. But you should know better than me if you have for example a tabulator character or sth. like that  at the beginning of your file.

Comment: Sometimes it can be indeed a tabulator (or more) and spaces.

Comment: I modified the code a little bit but this might not be the modification you need as it will also remove the white spaces from the textline you will use at the end to rename the file. This can also be fixed, of course.

Comment: The public function fails, it doesn't seem to recognize New RegExp. Datatype is not recognized, the system says.

Comment: Please read the code! There is a comment what you need to do beforehand. **`Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`**

Comment: sorry...now it works. Only as you mentioned now my titles are also without spaces. Do  you have a solution for this. Again sorry for my lack of knowledge and maybe stupid questions...

Comment: You only edited the main code right? Because there i now get an error "Byref arguments do not match".

Comment: Right, sorry. Also adjusted the function.

Comment: Awesome, your the best!! Merry x-mas

Comment: After a 198 txt files, the procedures crashes and mentions "Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)", is there a solution to bypass this error?

Comment: Which line? What are the values of the variables? I strongly guess it's the line `fil.Name = Trim(TextLine) & ".txt"` and the reason is that `textline` is not a valid filename.

Comment: I mentioned that you need to implement error handling for that.

Comment: Yes indeed that's where it goes wrong, but how can i handle this error?

Comment: Either error handling or as I did add code to check for this kind of problem. The next issue now might be that a file already exists! I'd suggest that you try to fix that on your own and if you get stuck create a new post. Otherwise this will end as spoon feeding. You need to try for yourself otherwise you will not learn anything.

Comment: Ok, but the code still seems to fail. Could it help the code with the parameter when a letter is found that is the start of the title and that it should Always cutoff after the word transcript?

Comment: Try to implement some erro handling because I do not know what should happen in case of an error. I modified the code for that part with "brutal" force.

Comment: Hi i changed a bit of the code, but i would like the files which are seen as double to be skipped: